# How to align bootstrap datepicker with bootstrap column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 and bootstrap datepicker v1.6.4. I have embedded the datepicker inside a div with class col-md-6, but it doesn't seem fill up the column.

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-lg-5 text-left">Select Date:</label>
     <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose your date..." readonly>
          <div id="datepicker" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap Datepicker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
```

JavaScript:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Datepicker -->
<script src="bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

[datepicker-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU1dU.png)

[datepicker-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zczYo.png)

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: can you give a link to a page where this is?

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be some left padding on component. Find the source of this styling and overwrite it

`.datepicker-inline` class may includes some padding or width constaint or perhaps inherits it from some other class